# Scala bug? DelayedInit and Implicits

Tags: scala

I've found extremely weird behaviour (scala 2.9.1 ) using and defining implicit values, and wondering if anyone can explain it, or if it's a scala bug?

I've created a self contained example:

```
object AnnoyingObjectForNoPurpose {

  trait Printer[T] {
    def doPrint(v: T): Unit
  }

  def print[T : Printer](v: T) = implicitly[Printer[T]].doPrint(v)


  trait DelayedRunner extends DelayedInit {
    def delayedInit(x: => Unit){ x }
  }

  // this works, as it should
  object Normal extends DelayedRunner {
      implicit val imp = new Printer[Int] {
        def doPrint(v: Int) = println(v + " should work")
      }

      print(343)
  }

  // this compiles, but it shouldn't
  // and won't run, cause the implicit is still null
  object FalsePositive extends DelayedRunner {

      print(123)

      implicit val imp = new Printer[Int] {
        def doPrint(v: Int) = println(v + " should not compile")
      }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val imp = new Printer[Int] {
      def doPrint(v: Int) = println(v + " should work")
    }

    print(44)
    // print(33.0) // correctly doesn't work 

    Normal // force it to run
    FalsePositive // force this to run too 
  }
}
```

Comment: I find it confusing, that you reuse T as identifier in def print (line 7) which leads to the question, is `implicitly [Printer [T]]` an implicitly Printer of Printer? Wouldn't a different identifier help to avoid confusion here?

Comment: @userunknown I'm not quite sure what you mean, or of a simpler way of writing it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? You say things like "this compiles, but it shouldn't", but that's a statement, not a question. What _is_ your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you changed your definition of `delayInit` to be a no-op, i.e.

```
def delayedInit(x: => Unit) {  }
```

Then in your main method do something like

```
println("FP.imp: " + FalsePositive.imp)
```

As expected that will print `FP.imp: null`, but the real point of the exercise is to illustrate that the block that defines the body of `FalsePositive` is acting like a regular class body, not a function body.  It's defining public members when it sees `val`, not local variables.

If you added a method to `AnnoyingObjectForNoPurpose` like the following, it wouldn't compile because `print`'s implicit requirement isn't satisfied.

```
def fails {
  print(321)
  implicit val cantSeeIt = new Printer[Int] {
    def doPrint(v: Int) = println(v + " doesn't compile")
  }
}
```

However if you defined a class along the same principle, it would compile, but fail at runtime when initialized, just like your `FalsePositive` example.

```
class Fine {
  print(321)
  implicit val willBeNull = new Printer[Int] {
    def doPrint(v: Int) = println(v + " compiles, but fails")
  }
}
```

To be clear, the compile behavior of `Fine` has nothing to do with the presence of the `implicit`. Class/object initializers are very happy to compile with `val` initializers which reference undefined `val`s.

```
object Boring {
  val b = a
  val a = 1
  println("a=%s b=%s".format(a, b))
}
```

`Boring` compiles just fine and when it is referenced, it prints `a=1 b=0`

It seems like your question boils down to "Should the body of a class/object deriving from `DelayedInit` be compiled as if it's a class body or a function block?"

It looks like Odersky picked the former, but you're hoping for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

That's the same bug as if I write this:

```
object Foo {
   println(x)
   val x = 5
}
```

It ain't a bug.  Your constructor flows *down* the object body and happens in order.   `DelayedInit` isn't the cause.   This is why you need to be careful when using val/vars and ensure they init first.  This is also why people use lazy val's to resolve initialization order issues.